# How to Fix Loop in a template excel format

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a workbook for payroll data from which I need to create a ready template payslip. The identifier when creating a new worksheet will be the name of the employee. The template is created but I have trouble reflecting the data in loop. it's not returning the data I need.

I'm using a simple VBA as I've been trying to create the payroll slip manually:

```
Set wsPay = .Sheets("Payroll")
Set wsTEMP = .Sheets("Template")

Range("F6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = wsPay.Range("AI" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row + 1

Range("J6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = wsPay.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row + 1

Range("B7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = wsPay.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row + 1

Range("H7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = wsPay.Range("AJ" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row + 1

Range("K7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = wsPay.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row + 1

Range("B8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = wsPay.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row + 1

Range("H8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = wsPay.Range("AK" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row + 1

Range("K8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = wsPay.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row + 1
```

in the loop, whereas the formula needed to return the corresponding cell data in that column range is not capturing.

Comment: Beg your pardon, but what this formula should calculate? For now it just stores a number...

Comment: Hi yes it should store data coming from the payroll sheet then loops since im creating a payslip for a hundred people, it does create a payslip template of a hundred but the storing/capturing data from payroll sheet to the created template slips is not capturing in my loop it gives me different or wrong data

Comment: I guess, you need `Value` instead of `FormulaR1C1` and `.Offset(1)` instead of `.Row + 1`

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're doing, but here's some commentary on your code which maybe you use to figure out the issue.

There's a lot of improvement that can likely be done with these statements:

```
Range("J6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = wsPay.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row + 1
```

- You don't need to use `Select` ([see this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)). You can be more succinct by typing `Range("J6").FormularR1C1 =`
- You're setting the value on to be a number. Specifically a row plus 1. Is that intentional? Probably better to use `Range("J6").Value2`. Assuming you don't want any calculations or anything else in the cell, the FormulaR1C1 will technically work in this case, but not really the best approach.
- You're doing something wrong with the `wsPage.Range`. Assuming you're on 2007 or higher this will ALWAYS return 1,048,577. You're setting it to the bottom cell in Column E (the count of total rows in a cell) but then you're using `End(xlDown)`, which will do nothing since you're already at the bottom of the worksheet. Either use `xlUp` or start somewhere higher... `e1`?